# Quotient of two Free Abelian Groups (Checking Computation)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, free-groups, free-abelian-group

Let $A=\langle a-b,c\rangle$ be the free abelian group generated by $a-b$ and $c$.

Let $B=\langle 2a-2b+c,2c\rangle$ denote the free abelian group generated by $2a-2b+c$ and $2c$.

I would like to compute the quotient $A/B$. I got $\mathbb{Z}_4\oplus\mathbb{Z}_2$ as such:

Quotienting by $B$ is implies $2c=0$ and $2a-2b+c=0$. This implies $c=2b-2a$, so $4(b-a)=0$.

So $c$ generates $\mathbb{Z}_2$ and $a-b$ generates a $\mathbb{Z}_4$. Is the above correct?

Thanks.

Comment: This doesn't make much sense. What are $a$, $b$ and $c$?

Comment: $a$, $b$, $c$ are basis elements of a free abelian group $G=\mathbb{Z}a\oplus\mathbb{Z}b\oplus\mathbb{Z}c$.

Comment: You argue that, in the quotient, $c$ is in the group generated by $b - a$. So your last sentence won't imply that the quotient is a *direct* product of the group generated by the class of $c$ by the group generated by the class of $a - b$.

Comment: So, $A$ is the free abelian group of rank $2$ on $x:=a-b$ and $y:=c$, and $B$ is the subgroup generated by the vectors $(2,1)$ and $(0,2)$. The quotient is generated by $(1,0)+B$, which has order $4$, so it is isomorphic to $Z_4$.